# before() failing while comparing with nulls

Tags: java, function, if-statement, logic

I am using `.before()` function to make sure the older value is less than the newer value but the issue is that I am allowing the user to have nulls in any of those two values so when `.before()` compares the value to `null`... it fails.

My code:

```
public getDetails(Calendar older, Calendar newer) {
    if (older.before(newer)) {
        System.out.println("Works");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Works");
    }
}
```

One alternative I thought of was to check if ANY of the value is null and have the function pass.

So I tried:

```
if ((older || newer) == null || older.before(newer))
```

Is there a cleaner and shorter way to doing this?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're allowing the user to pass in `null`? It doesn't seem like handling that case is part of the purpose of your function, so you probably shouldn't allow it to occur at all.

Comment: @RedRoboHood Yes, I am handling nulls for pulling different lists so a user can have either or both as nulls

Comment: What do you mean by "pulling different lists"?

Comment: @RedRoboHood for example, if newer date is not entered. I am pulling a list including all details upto the older date etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not passing null is better... Java 8 has the option to Optional... Which implies that no value may be supplied... Optional.isPresent()...

The code you supplied is not going to work, because first older and newer are compared, then their result to null, and at the same time older.before(newer)

```
if ((older || newer) == null || older.before(newer))
```

This should do, one comparison at the time

```
if( older==null || newer==null || older.before(newer))
```